# Documents in documents web part opening online even after changing settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, document-library

Documents in documents web part opening online even after changing the following settings:

1. under site collection administration to open documents by default in client application
2. Changing setting for the document library to open documents in client application

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following things to narrow down your issue:

1. Check if all types of documents open in the browser?
2. Check if you can open the documents in the client application in the document library instead of document web part.
3. If the issue only happened in the web part, try to delete and re-add it in this or other pages and check again.
4. Check if this issue happened on other document libraries.
5. If it happened on all libraries, what’s the browser you used to open document? Try to use other browser and check again. If you use IE, go to IE tools->Internet Options->Manage add-ons->check if “SharePoint OpenDocuments Class” add-on is enabled.